# how to print the name of the files

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to print the name of the files I upload but for some reason it print only the first file.

The script allows me to upload unlimited files, and that's why it's array of files.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var $form = $(this);
    var act = 'add';

    var files = $form.find('.file-field').prop('files');
    var names = "";

    $.each(files,function(i, file){
        name = file.name;
        alert(name);
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif"  id="uploadFile0"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `prop()` return value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.

Taken from **http://api.jquery.com/prop/**

So use `each()` iterate over  jQuery objects and do the rest as same

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this);
  var act = 'add';

  $form.find('.file-field').each(function() {
    var files = $(this).prop('files');
    var names = "";
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
      var name = file.name;
      alert(name);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" id="uploadFile0" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" id="uploadFile0" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

**Update :** You can simplify your code

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $form.find('.file-field').each(function() {
    var name = this.files[0].name;
    alert(name);
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" id="uploadFile0" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" id="uploadFile0" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @Roi : one is for iterating over each input field, second is for ietrating over filelist